# How Calculate X2 Y2 From given Example

Tags: javascript, canvas, trigonometry, offset

How to calculate X2 Y2 (Offset from left top corner) From given example.
I have red values from Image and i want calculate grey values

(Computing in JS)

[See example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk2gO.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This post might point you in the right direction, to at least get the X2 Y2: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86755/how-to-calculate-corner-positions-marks-of-a-rotated-tilted-rectangle

The formula they have is:

```
X = x*cos(θ) - y*sin(θ)
Y = x*sin(θ) + y*cos(θ)
```